# Win32:Process SetProcessAffinityMask crashes my Perl

Tags: perl, winapi

I have a Perl script running that acts like a service, one of the things I do with it is use it to spawn other processes.  Some of these processes are executables and some are perl scripts.

At times I want to set the processor affinity on some these processes.  I use SetProcessAffinityMask to do this, for the executables everything works as expected.  For perl scripts doing this crashes my Perl service.  I am running activestate perl 5.8.8, I have done some googling and have found [one other thread](http://objectmix.com/perl/79759-win32-process-setprocessaffinitymask-existing-process-perl-crash.html) that mentions a similar issue as to what I am seeing and the consensus of that thread seems to be with the way Perl was compiled.
Any ideas or suggestions?

---

I have pinpointed the issue down to the actual Perl I am running.  It seems that ActiveState Perl 5.8.8 has an issue with SetProcessAffinityMask().  I uninstalled 5.8.8 and installed 5.10.1, used the same exact code and everything worked as expected.

---

I am using Win32::Process:Create and utilizing the Win32::Process:setAffinityMask

Comment: Any chance of you linking to those threads for us?  Offhand I'd say the answer is "reinstall or recompile Perl".. :)

Comment: How do you spawn new processes in Perl? Do you use `fork()` or do you use something like `Win32::Process::Create`?

Comment: (I have merged the accounts and edited the follow-ups into the question; you should be the question-owner again)

Answer (score 0):

That [sample code](http://objectmix.com/perl/79759-win32-process-setprocessaffinitymask-existing-process-perl-crash.html) (which is somebody else's code, right?) is crap -- passing a hard-coded process ID to `Win32::Process::Open` is almost certain to fail. How are you using the methods from `Win32::Process`?

Also the doc for [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::Process) notes:

```
    $ProcessObj->SetProcessAffinityMask($processAffinityMask)
        Set the process affinity mask. Only available on Windows NT.
```

but that might just mean that the documentation is outdated.

```
use strict;
use Win32::Process;
use Win32;
my $obj;
my $pid=2216;
my $iflags;
Win32::Process::Open($obj,$pid,$iflags) or die;
my $processAffinityMask;
my $systemAffinityMask;
$obj->GetProcessAffinityMask($processAffinityMask, $systemAffinityMask) or die;
$obj->SetProcessAffinityMask($processAffinityMask) or die;
```